# Как добавить синтаксическое дерево(построено генератором кода antlr4) во вкладку TabPane в Java?

Tags: java, tab, antlr

я использую генератор парсеров ANTLR4 в Intellij idea(Java) для лексического(таблица токенов) и синтаксического(синтаксическое дерево) анализа кода, написанного на C++.
Табличку токенов я легко смог добавить во вкладку TabPane
[image]

А синтаксическое дерево никак не получается добавить во вторую вкладку, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать? Спасибо большое!
Сейчас оно открывается в новом окне
[image]
Прилагаю код построения дерева
[image]
Прилагаю код TabPane[image]

Comment: Код принято вставлять в виде текста. Отвечающим приходится с ним работать. Это крайне неуважительно заставлять их перепечатывать все это вручную. Большинство пользователей просто проигнонируют этот вопрос и вы останетесь без ответа, а в худшем случае, проголосуют за закрытие из-за проблем с качеством вопроса. Тем более код может быть проиндексирован поисковыми системами и таким образом ваш вопрос может помочь  другим пользователям (чего не будет в случае с картинкой).Да и хостинг картинок не обязан хранить ее вечно.Он удалит ее через время и вопрос станет бессмысленным для других пользователей